# difference between an engine and a library

Tags: terminology

I'd like to know the difference between a library and an engine. I've searched some information and if I'm not wrong, an engine gives you more options and makes work easier than a library.

An engine can help you for example handling user input or handling collisions but I don't know how. I mean I've been using SFML and it has a function that detects collision between two rectangles. You can handle user input too.

How does an engine work? In what ways handling collisions for example is easier with an engine than with a library?

Comment: "How does an engine work?" is too broad a question for this site's format, unfortunately. Handling collisions is not, per se, easier with an engine versus a library, it may be easier with a *specific* engine over a *specific* library, but the reverse could also be true.

Comment: A library provides a collection of functions that usually include low level stuff such as window creation, graphics, etc. An engine sits usually on top of a library and provides a higher level set of functions such as a scene graph, object management, game GUI, etc. Usually the result of wiring the pieces of the library for your purpose. That is an engine.

Comment: OK, that really helped me.